# Error correcting code? - using RGB space with a lookup table

Tags: discrete-signals, distortion

This problem could be thought about as how to transmit a signal with 3x8bit RGB in a way that is robust to the distortion of antialiasing blends colors.

**The context:** I need to rewrite a short utility library, to get it working with the Brave browser (My actual question isn't about brave per se.)

[canvas-color-tracker](https://github.com/vasturiano/canvas-color-tracker) - [example of it being used](https://vasturiano.github.io/canvas-color-tracker/example/canvas-medium.html) and [src/index.js](https://github.com/vasturiano/canvas-color-tracker/blob/master/src/index.js)  is short

**The HTML canvas is used for mouse over and clicks to determine what object is under the cursor.**

To use it with circles, you register your circle to get a color, then draw the circle in that color. Then to determine what is under the cursor, you get the color with [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

The trouble is what to do about anti-aliasing, the browser doesn't allow that to be turned off, and I want to be able to return nothing rather than collide with another uninvolved circle when it's edges blend into another color)

---

**Assuming the anti-aliasing blends linearly** How to create an ordering of points in 8bit RGB space, such that the minimum number of points are colinear without knowing the final total number of points? **What is a reasonable heuristic for this?**

---

Addendum, I am doing this because Brave will choose a color channel at random and randomly vary the lowest bit of it - [bit fiddling](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/9591) as a privacy feature prevent fingerprinting.

Comment: I'm not fully following your use case, I must admit. Am I understanding this correctly: You want to transport an amount of information with a **single** RGB pixel? If that's the case, *how many bits of information do you need to encode*?

Comment: It's like using a single RGB pixel to encode a way to lookup an item. Wanting to store as many unique items as possible, least probability of an error due to the anti-aliasing at edges of the represented items.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a "I hope I understand your question right" answer, but seeing I have to leave for the day:

Randomizing the LSBs of *all* the three color channels would obviously reduce the amount of information a single pixel could carry would reduce the amount of information carried in that color from 24 to 21 bits.

Picking one randomly and randomly varying that has an entropy $1+ \log_2 3$ bits, so you reduce the information contained in that pixel's color from 24 to ca 21.415 bit. This doesn't look like it seriously introduces any privacy there.

It will be impossible to find a 24-bit code that has a rate higher than 21.415/24 that can correct 3 bit errors, so, honestly, you usually simply wouldn't need to use error correction at all.

Still, I think they're doing that for a reason – probably it breaks an existing system of identification. There's no "provable" privacy to be won here, just an "against a single implementation" privacy.

> Assuming the anti-aliasing blends linearly

Not the case, usually; you use low-pass filters that are more than a linear interpolation to get acceptably-looking edges.

> How to create an ordering of points in 8bit RGB space, such that the minimum number of points are colinear without knowing the final total number of points?

Oh, that's a **very** interesting problem!

However, we *do* know from linear algebra how to find linearly independent vectors in a vectors space (e.g. simply choosing canonical base vectors that are all zero but for one entry, or taking a set of random vectors and doing Gram-Schmidt on them).

In this case, our vector space is 3-dimensional. In a three-dimensional space, you get exactly 3 bases in each orthogonal base system, soooo, that's three code points that are orthogonal only! That's very few.

Now, if you add two of these code points, you get another code point, which isn't colinear with any of the existing code points, and since 3-choose-2 is 3, you get three new code points, for a total of 6. You can also add up all three original bases and get one new. OK, so 7 code points.

You can iteratively repeat that, but you have to be careful: You will find multiple ways to calculate the same code point later on, or even multiples of that, and at some point, your elements' coordinates can get larger than your 8-bit integers can hold. But since essentially computers are fast, and the number of things you'll get will be still quite low, you can probably really just brute force your way out of this reasonably by going through all possible pairs of points you have, adding them, and checking that the result is not a multiple of any existing point.

Comment: Apparently - Chromium renderer, Blink uses Skia which uses Analytic AntiAliasing https://groups.google.com/g/skia-discuss/c/OUzwQqxsCmo

It's not clear to me that the channels wouldn't be blended together by the same factor, e.g. 0.5 * [R, G, B] at the edge of a path. But I don't deeply get the anti-aliasing

Comment: And thank you, this helps my thinking.

Iterative checking, solves the formal non-colinear problem, but for my actual problem, I will want to use a heuristic, or something with constant time for registration

Comment: That has constant time. A correct algorithm is especially a correct heuristic, and in this case, the "right" algorithm is very cheap, so I'd strongly recommend using it. NB: you don't have to start with unit vectors / canonical bases.

Comment: @exrhizo re: anti-aliasing: it's not clear to me why it *would* be just a linear interpolation between two pixels. Looking at how the things in my browser look: it certainly depends on more than an environment of 1 pixel, so your interpretation can be ruled out.

Comment: Okay, you are right about constant time, I need to try to implement this

Comment: Perhaps I am using linear in a way different than what you mean. I am surprised by this picture actually, where there are some colors showing, when the original colors are pure white, pure black and middle gray. I don't know where the artifact was added - https://imgur.com/a/aqcsFua - By linear I meant, R, G and B blend together by the same amount (maybe that depends on color space used)

Comment: yeah, but no, that usually doesn't happen in better anti-aliasing

Comment: (problem is probably in the sub-pixel interpolation; you call it artifact, I call it decades of human perception modelling and image processing theory)

Comment: What I ended up doing was a bit reversed morton code, so that the lowest bits would be used last as a way to spread the points out with the intuition that packed points would collide more.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question to focus on the colinear part and accept this answer if you want to expand on the algorithm you mention, as I think about it, I imagine it is maybe something like using factors of the unit vectors that are prime numbers, but it isn't obvious to me from this.